# "Unlocker" equivalent for Vista64?

Tags: unlock, vista64

Cedrick Collomb's [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) is one of the most useful utilities I've ever come across - when I come across an issue in compiling that some file is locked I can just right click on the file, click "Unlocker", and it will tell me what has the file (similar to Who Lock Me?) and I can remove the handles, kill the process, whatever. It's really nice.

However it doesn't work in Vista64. I'm not sure if it works in Vista32 but I'm currently running Vista64 at home and soon will be using it at work, too.

Does anyone know of a comparable utility that works in Vista64?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found one - [LockHunter](http://lockhunter.com/)

Answer (score 4):

I know that Windows 7 will have this functionality built directly into it.  In the mean time, check out [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).  It can identify the process that has the file hook as wel as remove the hook(s).  Its got tonnes of other uses, but I've primarily used it for that.

Answer (score 1):

[Unlocker 64 bit](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/#download) has been available for a while...